# Investigating encoding error

Tags: r, encoding, rvest

I'd like to scrape the following web page:

http://www.oricon.co.jp/rank/js/w/2017-01-16/p/4/

But there's some issue with the encoding:

```
library(rvest)
URL = 'http://www.oricon.co.jp/rank/js/w/2017-01-16/p/4/'
read_html(URL)
```

> Error in `eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos)` : 
>     input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0xFA 0xB1 0x90 0xE7 [6003]

The page is clearly in Japanese; no encoding was required for the first three pages, for example:

```
read_html('http://www.oricon.co.jp/rank/js/w/2017-01-16/p/2/')
# {xml_document}
# <html>
# [1] <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">\n  <meta charset="shi ...
# [2] <body id="container">&#13;\n<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11 ...
```

This page behaves as expected and I can extract the contents I want without issue.

I tried being more explicit with the encoding, using the approach suggested by Hadley on the `rvest` Issues Tracker [here](https://github.com/hadley/rvest/issues/117):

```
library(httr)
guess_encoding(content(GET(URL), 'raw'))
#     encoding language confidence
# 1 ISO-8859-1       pt       0.72
# 2 ISO-8859-2       ro       0.44
# 3      UTF-8                0.10
# 4  Shift_JIS       ja       0.10
# 5    GB18030       zh       0.10
# 6     EUC-JP       ja       0.10
# 7     EUC-KR       ko       0.10
# 8       Big5       zh       0.10
# 9 ISO-8859-9       tr       0.01
```

None of these are right. The language is wrong for all but `Shift_JIS` and `EUC-JP`, but both of those produce similar errors (the troublesome byte codes are different):

```
read_html(URL, encoding = 'Shift_JIS')
```

> Error in `eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos)` : 
>     input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0xFA 0xB1 0x90 0xE7 [6003]

```
read_html(URL, encoding = 'EUC-JP')
```

> Error in `eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos)` : 
>     input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0x8F 0x54 0x8A 0xD4 [6003]

Using some of the other suggested encodings produces no *error*, *per se*, but the output is gobbledygook:

```
cell.xp = '//div[@class="inner" and ./a[contains(@href, "prof")]]'
read_html(URL, encoding = 'ISO-8859-1') %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = cell.xp) %>% html_nodes('h2') %>% 
  html_text %>% tail(6)
# [1] "\u0082æ\u0082Ñ\u0082·\u0082Ä"                                                      
# [2] "\u0083n\u0083b\u0083s\u0081[\u0083G\u0083\u0093\u0083h"                            
# [3] "THE IDOLM@STER CINDERELLA GIRLS STARLIGHT MASTER 07 \u0083T\u0083}\u0083J\u0083j!!"
# [4] "Dear Bride"                                                                        
# [5] "Fantastic Time"                                                                    
# [6] "Hey Ho"
```

The Roman-alphabet characters are appearing just fine, but the hiragana/kanji/katakana have been lost/mangled.

Is there an encoding that `guess_encoding` failed to mention that might solve my problem? Is there any way to figure out which characters on the page are causing issues and hopefully exclude them? What does the 6003 mean in the error message?

`sessionInfo` for package version reference:

```
# R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
# Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
# Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
# 
# locale:
#  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
#  [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
#  [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
# [10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
# 
# attached base packages:
# [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
# 
# other attached packages:
# [1] rvest_0.3.2.9000 xml2_1.1.0.9000 
# 
# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#  [1] httr_1.2.1      magrittr_1.5    R6_2.1.3        tools_3.3.1     withr_1.0.2    
#  [6] curl_1.2        Rcpp_0.12.9     memoise_1.0.0   knitr_1.15.1    git2r_0.18.0   
# [11] digest_0.6.11   devtools_1.12.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following our discussion in the comments: The encoding should be `Shift_JISX0213` as `Shift_JIS` somehow is not platform/setup independent.

```
require(rvest)
url <- "http://www.oricon.co.jp/rank/js/w/2017-01-16/p/4/"
cell.xp = '//div[@class="inner" and ./a[contains(@href, "prof")]]'
xml2::read_html(url, encoding = "Shift_JISX0213") %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = cell.xp) %>% html_nodes('h2') %>% 
  html_text %>% tail(6)

[1] "よびすて"                                                      
[2] "ハッピーエンド"                                                
[3] "THE IDOLM@STER CINDERELLA GIRLS STARLIGHT MASTER 07 サマカニ!!"
[4] "Dear Bride"                                                    
[5] "Fantastic Time"                                                
[6] "Hey Ho"
```

Why `shift_jis` should do the trick? Even tho it does not work on all systems:

Have a look at the response header and the source code:

[image]

`shift_jis` and `Shift_JISX0213` work for me with the following setup: macOS Sierra 10.12.2

```
Session info --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
 system   x86_64, darwin13.4.0        
 ui       RStudio (1.0.44)            
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
 tz       Europe/Vienna               
 date     2017-01-16                  

Packages ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package  * version    date       source                        
 curl       2.3        2016-11-24 cran (@2.3)                   
 devtools   1.12.0     2016-06-24 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                
 digest     0.6.11     2017-01-03 cran (@0.6.11)                
 httr       1.2.1      2016-07-03 CRAN (R 3.2.5)                
 magrittr   1.5        2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                
 memoise    1.0.0      2016-01-29 CRAN (R 3.2.3)                
 R6         2.2.0      2016-10-05 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                
 Rcpp       0.12.9     2017-01-15 Github (RcppCore/Rcpp@f57467b)
 rvest    * 0.3.2.9000 2017-01-01 local                         
 selectr    0.3-0      2016-08-30 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                
 stringi    1.1.2      2016-10-01 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                
 stringr    1.1.0      2016-08-19 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                
 withr      1.0.2      2016-06-20 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                
 XML        3.98-1.5   2016-11-10 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                
 xml2     * 1.1.0.9000 2017-01-15 Github (hadley/xml2@d36883c)
```

Comment: Strangely that code doesn't work for me, even with development version of `xml2`. But thanks for pointing out what to look for about encoding in the source -- I had scanned looking for something like that but came up short.

Comment: Could you add your session info? Someone on Windows seems to have gotten it to work, but I'm still having no luck: http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/31894/%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%82%92%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%83%94%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%81%97%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A7%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99/

Comment: Just added it. Hopefully that helps

Comment: According to [this](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/31894/%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%82%92%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%83%94%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%81%97%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A7%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99?noredirect=1#comment31041_31894) comment, there is more than one version of `Shift_JIS` out there, and `0xFA 0xB1` = 﨑 may not be in the standard charset used by `encoding = 'Shift_JIS'`. Per the recommendation there, though, `encoding = 'Shift_JISX0213'` did work. Seems like a subtle issue

Comment: @MichaelChirico Just edited my answer. Thats for sharing the insight

Comment: Strictly speaking, 﨑 isn't 0xFA 0xB1 in Shift_JISX0213 but CP932. Chrome treat Shift_JIS as alias of CP932. `printf "\xFA\xB1\x90\xE7"| iconv -f shift_jisx0213 -t utf-8` -> `郫千`, `printf "\xFA\xB1\x90\xE7"| iconv -f cp932 -t utf-8` -> `﨑千`